Pandas all() but with a threshold
Suppose we have the following dataframe and program logic
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'B': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]})


def more_than(series, threshold=5):
    try:
        trues = series.value_counts()[True]
        p = trues / len(series) * 100
    except KeyError:
        p = 0
    
    return True if p > threshold else False

df['compare'] = df['A'] > 5

print(more_than(df['compare']))

# True here

I'd like to have function similar to all(...) but with the possibility of a threshold (like above). It works as it should but I wondered if there's anything inbuilt and probably faster here.

Are you using percentage? perhaps df['A'].gt(5).mean() > (threshold/100)??

@Onyambu: Yes, percentage.

This has nothing to do with speed but rather readability. note that with all there is short-circuiting. but here, you are just comparing two values. so not similar to all function

@Onyambu: I know. I originally wanted to use all() (also because of the short circuiting), but then had to introduce that e.g. 95% or so "is also ok".

more_compare = lambda x, threshold = 5: series.mean()*100 > threshold

And yes, it has sth. to do with speed. This is performed on millions of rows.

@Onyambu: Make it an answer!

But you are simply comparing two values. all takes in a list of values. in your case, you are simply comparing the proportion of trues to the threshold. So only two values. No short-circuit, no loops. So I really do not understand why you are comparing this to the all function

You can use:
(df['A'].gt(5).mean()*100)>5

Output: True
Intermediates:
# df['A'].gt(5)
[False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, True]

# implicit conversion to integer
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

# average
0.5


Why mean(...) ?

By averaging the True (1) / False (0) you count their proportion ;)

Hmm... could you elaborate it bit more on this?

@Jan sure, I added the intermediate steps
